# If $A$ is a symmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}$, why is $PAP^t$ diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra Why is following correct:

Given a symmetric matrix $A$ on the field of the real numbers, why is that true that there exists an unitary matrix $P$ such that $PAP^t$ is a diagonal matrix?

I know that from the Spectral Theorem there exists a unitary matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal. However how can I conclude that $PAP^t$ is diagonal as well?

Thank you

Comment: Well, what does the word *unitary* mean? Are there relatinos between $P^{-1}$ and $P^t$?

Comment: Because for unitary (or orthogonal) matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$), $P^{-1} = P^t$.

Comment: Daniel can you explain why please?

Comment: @DanielFischer You got me. Haha  P.S. This is because $PP^t=I$ and the inverse is unique, if there exists one.

Comment: why does PPt = I?

Comment: @vondip I think this is the definition of a *unitary* matrix?

Comment: unitary means that P = P*, nobody said that P* = P^t, I only know that A = A^t

Comment: @vondip Unitary means $P^*P = I$. What you just wrote, $P = P^*$, is Hermitian.

Comment: You are right, P* = P^-1. How does this help me show that P^t = P^-1?

Comment: It doesn't, unless $P$ is real, so $P^* = \overline{P}^T = P^T$.

Comment: And the question assumes that we are working in the real field.

Comment: Would be better to call orthogonal rather than unitary...but this should be not a problem anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that this problem comes down to getting the definitions straight.  So here they are:

**Symmetric matrix**: a matrix $A$ is called symmetric when $A=A^T$.  If $A$ is a matrix of real entries, then we can say that $A$ is an instance of a "Hermitian" matrix

**Hermitian matirix** a matrix $A$ is Hermitian when $A=A^*$, that is, $A$ is equal to its own conjugate transpose.

Depending on the context, real symmetric matrices and complex Hermitian matrices might be referred to as **self-adjoint**.

**Orthogonal matrix:** a matrix $U$ is called orthogonal when $UU^T=1$.  If $U$ is a matrix of real entries, then we can say that $U$ is an instance of a "unitary" matrix

**Unitary matrix** a matrix $U$ is called unitary when $UU^*=1$.  That is, the inverse of $U$ is its conjugate transpose.

The spectral theorem could then be understood as follows:

Suppose that $A$ is any **normal** matrix (that is, $AA^*=A^*A$).  We can then find a matrix $P$ such that $PAP^*$ is diagonal.

If $A$ happens to be a real and symmetric matrix, then we can find a $P$ that is *not only* unitary, but also itself real.  That is, there is a real matrix $P$ such that $PAP^*$ is diagonal.  Since $P$ is real, this is the same as saying $PAP^T$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

This is a straightforward consequence of the spectral theorem. Let $u_1=p_1+iq_1,\ \ldots,\ u_n=p_n+iq_n$ be an orthonormal eigenbasis of $A$, where $u_1,\ldots,u_{k_1}$ correspond to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$. Since $\lambda_1$ is real, we have $Ap_\ell=\lambda_1p_\ell$ and $Aq_\ell=\lambda_1q_\ell$ for $\ell=1,2,\ldots,k_1$. Hence every vector in $\mathcal{B}=\{p_1,\ldots,p_{k_1},q_1,\ldots,q_{k_1}\}$ is either zero or an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. Hence the span of $\mathcal{B}$ is precisely the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. However, as all vectors in the **set** $\mathcal{B}$ are real, we can choose from its **real** span $k_1$ orthonormal eigenvectors. The similar holds for other eigenvalues. Put these orthonormal eigenvectors together, we obtain a real orthogonal matrix $S$ such that $AS=SD$, i.e. $S^TAS=D$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [real Schur decomposition](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf). This gives you an orthogonal (meaning *real unitary*) $U$ and a quasitriangular (blockdiagonal with diagonal blocks of order at most $2$) $T$, with each block of order $2$ having conjugate pairs of eigenvalues. Since $A$ is real symmetric, we know that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, so $T$ is diagonal.

By the way, in [the above paper](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf), what you're asking is a corollary (on the last page).